# How to initialize local field from server query field?

Tags: apollo-client

I'm migrating from Apollo client 2 to Apollo client 3 (React).

Resolvers are now deprecated so I'm moving to Local-only fields.

Either using reactive variable or writeQuery how to initialize a local field from one retrieved from server ?

If I go with a reactive variable, how do I initialize it from the first hit to server ?
If I go with writeQuery, how do I intercept first query callback ?

Here is my current code using resolvers :

```
const LAYER = gql`
    query Layer($layerId: Int!) {
        layer(id: $taskId) {
            id
            name
            visibleByDefault
            isCheckedForDisplay @client
        }
    }
`;

const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    resolvers: {
        LayerType: {
            // Init from visibleByDefault from server
            isCheckedForDisplay: layer => layer.visibleByDefault,
        },
        Mutation: {
            toggleCheckedForDisplay: (_, variables, { cache, getCacheKey }) => {
                const id = getCacheKey({ __typename: 'LayerType', id: variables.id });
                const fragment = gql`
                    fragment isCheckedForDisplayLayer on LayerType {
                        isCheckedForDisplay
                    }
                `;
                const layer = cache.readFragment({ fragment, id });
                const data = { ...layer, isCheckedForDisplay: !layer.isCheckedForDisplay };
                cache.writeData({ id, data });
                return null;
            },
        }
    }
});
```

I don't know how but the query resolver seams to be called at initialization only and then the value from mutation is used. Is the same mechanism in place in Apollo client 3 ?

EDIT:

Here is what it would look like in Local only field :

```
typePolicies: {
    CalendarType: {
        fields: {
            isCheckedForDisplay : {
                read(isCheckedForDisplay /* = default value from other field "visibleByDefault" */ ) {
                    return isCheckedForDisplay;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```